# What is the Difference between Data.Datatable and System.Data.Datatable?

Tags: powershell, object

When creating scripts in PowerShell that create tables, I understand that are many ways to create a table.  I was wondering if anyone knows which way is better and what is the difference between them.  Which way is the best? Which way is more efficient?

```
$table = New-object Data.Datatable 
$table = New-object System.Data.Datatable
```

Or maybe tables are not as efficient as other methods.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference.

Powershell will "assume" the `System.` part of .NET calls, example:

```
PS C:\> New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

AcceptButton                       : 
ActiveMdiChild                     : 
AllowTransparency                  : False
....

PS C:\> New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

AcceptButton                       : 
ActiveMdiChild                     : 
AllowTransparency                  : False
....
```

Both returned objects are identical, but because `System` is basically a default in powershell this will work fine, there are a few other situations with similar things, e.g.

```
PS H:\> New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex ".+"

Options MatchTimeout      RightToLeft
------- ------------      -----------
   None -00:00:00.0010000       False

PS H:\> New-Object Regex ".+"

Options MatchTimeout      RightToLeft
------- ------------      -----------
   None -00:00:00.0010000       False
```

Because `System.Text.RegularExpression` is default resolvable.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference is using the full name versus the shortened name. By using System.Data.Datatable you have told PowerShell directly where to pull the information for creating the Datatable object.